# remove a ros package in workspace

Tags: catkin-make, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, I  want to remove ros package which installed from source. Using **wstool** retrieves from source and **catkin_make** to build.
I just deleted the package in **/src**, and any related files in **/build** and **/devel** and **catkin_make** again.

Could any give me suggestions to remove that package professionally.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222181/remove-a-ros-package-in-workspace/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-12-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on 2016-02-12**:
I wonder do you get a more professional solution now. I am facing this problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the standard way to do it.

If you're not quite sure what to remove in the build and devel spaces you can simply remove the whole directory and rebuild.

If you use the isolated builds it is easier to remove the whole directories.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1